# Unsupported Media Type (415) Error while implementing File upload using Jersey in Mule

Tags: http, file-upload, jersey, mule

I am trying to implement File Upload using Jersey module in Mule.

My mule flow looks like this:

```
<flow name="rest-service">
    <inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:9999/testupload"/>
    <jersey:resources>
        <component class="com.example.test.UploadFileResource"/>
    </jersey:resources>
</flow>
```

If I don't put @Consumes annotation in the resource method in UploadFileResource like below, the method gets called when an HTTP Post request is made using multipart/form-data  Content-type and I get HTTP 2xx status code:

```
@Path("/uploadfile")
public class UploadFileResource {

    @POST
    public Response uploadFile2(...) {
        logger.info("Multipart Upload");
        ...
    }
}
```

But when I put @Consumes annotation with MULTIPART_FORM_DATA Media Type like below, the method does not get called and I get HTTP 415 Unsupported Media type, even when the HTTP Post request is made using multipart/form-data Content-type:

```
@Path("/uploadfile")
public class UploadFileResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile2(...) {
        logger.info("Multipart Upload");
        ...
    }
}
```

Any idea why 415 status comes even when @Consumes Media type matches the HTTP Post Content-type header?

Comment: How does the input params of `#upload2()` method look like?

Comment: I tried two versions: One without any input arguments, i.e. `uploadFile2()`, and one with two input arguments, i.e. `uploadFile2(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail)`. I am getting the same result in both the cases.

Comment: Can you try to turn on the tracing support (as described [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/sandoz/entry/tracing_in_jersey)) and post the response headers to see what's going on?

Comment: do you have the jersey-multipart JAR on your classpath?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to register the **MultipartFeature** as described in the Jersey documentation, chapter [8.3.1.2 Registration](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#multipart).

Create a class something like this:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.verico.multipart.app;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MultiPartApp extends ResourceConfig {

public MultiPartApp() {
    super(MultiPartFeature.class);
    }
}
```

And add the following init-param to your Jersey servlet in web.xml:

```
     <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.verico.multipart.app.MultiPartApp</param-value>
    </init-param>
```